# How to let java applet download file

Tags: java, c#, applet, unmanaged

I am new to Java Applets.

I have the following situation: the client asks for a Java Applet to do Function1, i already have this Function1 developed and tested but in C#. so i say that i can use my C# dlls in Java applet.

I already tried to use [UnmanagedExports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) and it works fine with simple cases, **but i faced a problem when i have dependencies for the dll that is called from Java Applet**. the problem is that Java Applet crashes when the dll have any dependencies and i did not find any solution for this case.

**My Questions are:**

1- How to solve dependencies problem using UnmanagedExports?

2- If no solution for problem 1, what is the best approach that i should use to complete this task.

I think that Java Applets can setup an application on client PC, this application can run on a standalone app context (this application will be a c# application that can perform the task on the background and gives the feedback to the Java Applet). **Is this possible?**

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, try [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for resolving dependencies for a specific DLL.